# Creating an object and setting a property in one line or two

Tags: objective-c, variables, declared-property

I want to set a property but I'm not sure what is the best way to do it.  I can think of two ways to do this. By creating an object, storing it in a variable, and setting the property:

```
PropertyClass *myProperty = [[PropertyClass alloc] init];
self.myClassProperty = myProperty
```

Or by creating and setting in one line:

```
self.myClassProperty = [[PropertyClass alloc] init];
```

Are there any reasons one way is actually better/safer/faster/etc.? Is there a better way than the two I listed above?  I'm not sure if this makes a difference but this would be the first time the property is set.

Comment: If you check out the generate assembly for these you'll see that there is a subtle difference but I can;t read assembly so I have no idea what the effect is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equal but I always use the second one. Or the following

```
self.myClassProperty = [PropertyClass new];
```

The reason - in one line of code it is more difficult to make some stupid error. Also it is easier to read.